# You'll need a new app to open this - Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, file-association

See "Customer History Inquiry" screenshot. If we click on a link beginning with DEBIT or MASTERCARD to check on a Customer Payment, we have this popup that says "You'll need a new app...Always use this app" This started happening after we upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10. We can see the info we need to see; the only problem is that the popup is irritating. Any ideas on how to prevent the message from popping up? I've done a bit of searching with Google, but I was unable to find a solution.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Assign a program for the extension of the file your attempting to use.  This behavior is to be expected, your old choice, was not migrated to Windows 10 by design.  The "Always use this app" will help with that.  Without understand the logic behind the link, this question, will be very hard to answer.

Comment: [Winaero Tweaker](http://winaero.com/) can [disable this notification](http://imgur.com/XXvUcvW), and present you a dialog, with only the applications installed on your system.

Comment: [You'll Need a new app to open this (https)](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/id-2871812/app-open-https.html), this thread is close enough to your problem, since I suspect your application is just opening what basically is http traffic anyways.

Comment: What program are you using and what type of file is it trying to open? Did clicking the link work before?

Comment: You also might want to blur the customer id and his/hers account number in the attached image.

Comment: Thank you Ramhound. I tried Winaero Tweaker and it took away the 'Always use this app' & checkbox portion of the screenshot, the "You'll need a new app..." still pops up. Note: In case I wasn't clear, we can access the data we need. All we want to do is suppress / disable the popup from showing up. Is there a way to keep the popup from coming up if it is not going to suggest an app?

Comment: I think that it is not the word "debit" that triggers this, but rather I suspect that the "debit" links are using e.g. SSL (https). Ramhound is saying that your software, for some reason, does not know what to do with "https://" links. Rather than suppressing these notifications, it is better to try and figure out why they appear. Perhaps it is innocent, perhaps there was malware redirecting traffic based on keywords and your upgrade exposed it's presence (etc etc).